# Transforming and creating colums in a data frame using python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm working on building a python script that computes a d' statistic, using data from a CSV file, but the data in the CSV need to be manipulated so that the d' can be computed.  **My question: What code do I need to employ to transform the data in a data frame created from the csv.**

## **Details:**

I need to know how many items apply to one of four categories, either a hit, miss, false alarm, or correct rejection, where each category is defined by a stimulation and a detection, such that a

  **Hit**
  is signified by a "1" stimulation happening at the same time a "3" detection happens

  **Miss**
  is signified by "1" stimulation happening at the same time a "4" detection happens

  **False Alarm**
  is signified by "2" stimulation happening at the same time a "3" detection happens

  **Correct Rejection**
  is signified by "2" stimulation happening at the same time a "4" detection happens

The data I'm working with come to me in a CSV that lists the order in which stimulations and detections happen in one column, where once a stimulation is declared it applies to the detections that follow it until a new stimulation is called. It looks like this:

```
 Identifier
0         1
1         3
2         4
3         3
4         2
5         4
6         3
7         3
```

I want a data frame that looks like this:

```
 Stim Detect
0   1      3
1   1      4
2   1      3
3   2      4
4   2      3
5   2      3
```

## **Where I am now**

Looking around on here and by asking the few people I know who know python well, I was directed to use pandas to manipulate the data. have the data reading, and it outputing to a classifier value which can tell me if some row in the data frame is a hit, miss, false alarm, or correct rejection, but I don't have the above described data frame that does what I want. My code is below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

def stim(row):
    if row['Identifier'] == 1:
        return 1
    elif row['Identifier'] == 2:
        return 2

def detect(row):
    if row['Identifier'] == 3:
        return 3
    elif row['Identifier'] == 4:
        return 4

def classifier(row):
    return row['Stim']+row['Detect']

df['Stim']   = df.apply(stim,axis=1)
df['Detect'] = df.apply(detect,axis=1)
df['Classifier'] = df.apply(classifier,axis=1)
```

The data frame I get is this:

```
 Identifier Stim Detect Classifier
0         1    1    NaN        NaN
1         3  NaN      3        NaN
2         4  NaN      4        NaN
3         3  NaN      3        NaN
4         2    2    NaN        NaN
5         4  NaN      4        NaN
```

and the data frame that I want looks like this:

```
 Identifier Stim Detect Classifier
0         1    1    NaN        NaN
1         3    1      3          4
2         4    1      4          5
3         3    1      3          4
4         2    2    NaN        NaN
5         4    2      4          6
```

Comment: What do you mean you "don't have the above data frame that does what you want"?  What is the output you get, and how is it different from what you want?

Comment: @BrenBarn edited to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for identifying values in columns `Stim` and `Detect` and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for fill missing values in column `Stim`:

```
print df
   Identifier
0           1
1           3
2           4
3           3
4           2
5           4
6           3
7           3

df.loc[df['Identifier'] == 1, 'Stim'] = 1
df.loc[df['Identifier'] == 2, 'Stim'] = 2

df.loc[df['Identifier'] == 3, 'Detect'] = 3
df.loc[df['Identifier'] == 4, 'Detect'] = 4

#fill NaN by method ffill (propagate last valid observation forward to next valid)
df['Stim'] = df['Stim'].fillna(method='ffill')

df['Classifier'] = df['Stim'] + df['Detect']

print df
   Identifier  Stim  Detect  Classifier
0           1     1     NaN         NaN
1           3     1       3           4
2           4     1       4           5
3           3     1       3           4
4           2     2     NaN         NaN
5           4     2       4           6
6           3     2       3           5
7           3     2       3           5
```